# Thinktecture IdentityServer v3 with WindowsAuth

Tags: windows-authentication, identityserver3

I want to use Thinktecture IdentityServer as a token-provider and authenticate users against ActiveDirectory. So that token contain information about the domain user.

Both Client and IdentityServer (IIS) reside inside a Windows domain. When Client authenticates with the user account in IIS it uses WindowsAuth.

How can this be done? Appreciate for working code sample.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create a custom user service , see this example https://gist.github.com/tjrobinson/0ad6c790e90d7a385eb1

Comment: I'm sorry for being lame, but how do I use it? I've added it as a new class to the identityServer CustomUserService sample and then I should add also authenticationConfiguration to Startup.cs and it seems to me that something is missing.

Comment: Once you create your own user service you can then register it to factory , see the sample https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService

Comment: Well yes, I got so far. but what about Clients and Scopes here?

Comment: You would need to create your custom client store and custom scope store by defining your client and their available scopes in identityserver 3 . Parent path of the link that sent in my last comment has possibly all examples you need, try to search Flows.ClientCredentials

Comment: @Jenan what was your issue

Comment: @Chazt3n I wanted to implement the authentication against AD - windows authentication. I did this approach with the user service. I used this sample and works fine.