# IdentityServer3 + Active Directory + Self-Hosted User db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, identityserver3

I'm trying to find a solution to handle authentication on my new application, and I like the approach of IdentityServer3. I would like to hope my requirements are met by IdentityServer3 and it's just my lack of understanding due to my newness with the technology.

My requirements are as follows, and in order of desired execution:
1) If a user requesting authentication is a local (domain) user, they should be authenticated automatically using Active Directory.
2) If a user requesting authentication is not found in Active Directory, they should be authenticated against our own User table.
3) If a user requesting authentication is in neither Authority, we may choose to grant access via Google or Facebook credentials, but that's not a Phase I requirement.

I currently have a working proof of concept using IdentityServer3 as a standalone security server pulling records from the InMemoryUsers, InMemoryClients and InMemoryScopes, and I'm fairly sure I'll be able to expand on those concepts for pulling from our own database.

This problem comes when I try to use Active Directory as the first checkpoint.

I've looked at a couple of resources in an effort to accomplish the Active Directory, but I'm getting all tripped up as I'm not seeing any concise demo that shows the AD piece of the puzzle.

[TJ Robinson](https://gist.github.com/tjrobinson/0ad6c790e90d7a385eb1) has a Gist of an ActiveDirectoryUserService that implements IUserService, and that looks to be the most promising, but because of my n00b status, I can't seem to figure out how to roll it into the scheme.

I would really appreciate any suggestions, and, perhaps, links to examples of how to do AD authentication first with a fallback to local authentication.

Thanks in advance,
Ric

Comment: @sbennur looks like he's had a similar issue as well...at least when it comes to the AD part. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066039/c-net-validating-users-via-ldap-through-identityserver3> Unfortunately, he didn't show a full-ish example of how it was rolled in to the `Startup.cs` file of his IdentityServer3 project.

Answer (score 3):

In regard to your first requirement...

I believe you should examine the [Windows Authentication Service](https://github.com/IdentityServer/WindowsAuthentication). This is essentially a mini security-token-service that can work as an external identity provider to IdentityServer to provide Windows Authentication (over the WS-Fed protocol).

If you follow that link to the GitHub page, you will find two links to samples that can you get started with this component. One sample has both Identity Server and the Windows Authentication Service hosted separately and the other sample has them hosted together.

A **separate** option could be to use ADFS (if you have one) as an external identity provider.

Those samples include a custom user service (ExternalRegistrationUserService) that shows those windows users being mapped to an in-memory collection of users (in Identity Server). Your requirements will obviously demand a different implementation of that user service, but I hope this might help get your started with the Windows Auth part.

When I went through this exercise recently, I found a lot of good information in the [closed IdentityServer3 issues (for windows auth)](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20windows%20auth). Lots of good info on Stack Overflow as well; good luck!

Comment: thanks for the push. I have been working with the Windows Authentication Service that TJ Robinson has put together as referenced in my OP. Sadly, I don't have ADFS available, and I noticed in the first link you provided that seems to be using federation services. I'm looking at the second link now, but if anything else comes to mind, please let me know. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @rcastagna - the Windows Authentication Service communicates with Identity Server using the ws-fed protocol, but it is not ADFS. The service you referenced from TJ Robinson is a user service (not the same thing as this Windows Authentication Service).

Comment: Rob, I'm about as confused as a newborn in a gentlemen's club. I'm looking at the project you referred me to, and it plainly states that on IIS Express, I need to enable Windows Authentication. I can't have this project rely on only Windows Authentication. It needs to fail over from AD authentication to local/OpenId Connect if the user is not in AD. TJ's example provides me a user object after validating credentials, but I'm still getting an error saying the username/password is incorrect.

Comment: @rcastagna Yes, the Windows Authentication Service host needs Windows Authentication enabled, but the Identity Server **host** does not. They can be separate (as in one of those samples). I am not sure exactly how implementation would work for all your requirements. But, I would guess you could override AuthenticateExternalAsync and (in the event AD auth fails) redirect to IdentityServer's local login page to authenticate against your DB of local users. Looks like other people have tried to do similar things before...https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1696

Comment: Perhaps a federation server using IdentityServer as the base, then have individual Identity Servers, 1 for AD, 1 for internal DB, 1 for outside services (google, et al).  In the federated server, you should be able to cascade through the individual identity servers as you wish.  NOTE:  I have not done this myself and the little bit of understanding I have leads me to believe this can be done.